# HQL select statement with case

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is it posible to add a "Case" statement inside another "Case"?  It is not working my way.

`"case when (cia.nif is not null then cia.nif else case when(d.owner then c2.cif else '')) as cia_externa_nif, " +`

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
select
    order_id,
    max(timestamp),
    case when max(case when action = 'D' then timestamp end) is not null then 1 else 0 end myAlias
from ORDER
group by order_id
```

Comment: But what if, on that else 0 you have, you want else and another where clause, like "then 1 else when(x = "A" then action="E"